# How to remove element in an array by index in a Dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I got this dataframe:

```
+------+-----------+--------------------+                                       
|NewsId|    expNews|            transArr|
+------+-----------+--------------------+
|     1|      House|[house, HH, AW1, S] |
|     1|Republicans|[republicans, R, ...|
|     1|       Fret|[fret, F, R, EH1, T]|
|     1|      About|[about, AH0, B, A...|
```

I want to remove every element at index 0 in the arrays in column transArr.
Excpected result:

```
+------+-----------+--------------+                                       
|NewsId|    expNews|      transArr|
+------+-----------+--------------+
|     1|      House|[HH, AW1, S]  |
|     1|Republicans|[R, ...       |
|     1|       Fret|[F, R, EH1, T]|
|     1|      About|[AH0, B, A... |
```

Is there an easy way to to do this with Spark and Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code, It is faster than `slice` function

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------+-----------+---------------------+
|NewsId|expNews    |transArr             |
+------+-----------+---------------------+
|1     |House      |[house, HH, AW1, S]  |
|1     |Republicans|[republicans, R, ...]|
|1     |Fret       |[fret, F, R, EH1, T] |
|1     |About      |[about, AH0, B, A...]|
+------+-----------+---------------------+
```

```
scala> df
.withColumn(
    "modified_transArr",
    array_except(
        $"transArr",
        array($"transArr"(0))
    )
).show(false)
+------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
|NewsId|expNews    |transArr             |modified_transArr|
+------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
|1     |House      |[house, HH, AW1, S]  |[HH, AW1, S]     |
|1     |Republicans|[republicans, R, ...]|[R, ...]         |
|1     |Fret       |[fret, F, R, EH1, T] |[F, R, EH1, T]   |
|1     |About      |[about, AH0, B, A...]|[AH0, B, A...]   |
+------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was struggling for `$"transArr"(0)` . Damn

Answer (score 1):

For Spark 3.0+ you can use the [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter) function with an additional index argument:

```scala
df.withColumn("transArr", expr("filter(transArr, (x,i) -> i>0)"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A Spark 2.4+ solution :

```
df.withColumn("transArr", array_except($"transArr", slice($"transArr",1,1)))
```

`slice(arr,start,len)` will return the 1st element as an array, and Subtract it from original array using `array_except`

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `Spark UDF` Take the tail of the array. Ensure, you handle the null value in the column

```
    val parse_udf = udf(( value : Seq[String])=> value.tail)
df.withColumn("transArr", parse_udf($"transArr")).show()
```